# Where is the .idlerc folder on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, customization, python-idle

I'm looking for the .idlerc folder containing the definitions for IDLE.
My setup is Python 2.7.8 + Windows 8.1
This folder contains the "config-highlight.cfg" file, crucial to apply new custom themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is located in:

```
%userprofile%\.idlerc\
```

Comment: This is an annoying location; they should at least set the hidden attribute to match the Unix behavior. On Windows, configuration data belong in the user registry hive (stored in `%USERPROFILE%\NTUSER.DAT`) OR `%APPDATA%`; data that roam with the profile belong in `%APPDATA%`; and machine local data (e.g. cache files) belong in `%LOCALAPPDATA%`. These roughly correspond to Linux `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, `$XDG_DATA_HOME`, and `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to GalB1t's answer because it was incomplete. If searching doesn't work type

```
C:\Users\%userprofile%\.idlerc
```

into windows start menu search

*This is also true for Win 10

Comment: The posted directory path is wrong. Correct would be `C:\Users\%UserName%\.idlerc` if the user's profile directory is in directory `C:\Users` as on most Windows installations since Windows Vista. Better is using `%UserProfile%\.idlerc` as written by [GalB1t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4723246/galb1t) which is the correct directory path even on user's profile directory being on a different drive or in a different directory as also possible.